# TableView is invisible

Tags: qml

I'm trying to set something up, where there's a a `HorizontalHeaderView` that spans the entire width of the window, and a `TableView` that also spans the entire width of the window, along with stretching down to the bottom of the window. I also wanted a `TextField` and `Button` side by side, to sit on top of all this.

So far, I've gotten the `TextField` and `Button` to sit at the top, and part of the `HorizontalHeaderView` to be visible, but the `TableView` is completely invisible. I've tried fiddling around with `height`, `Layout.preferredHeight`, etc. but nothing makes it stretch to the bottom and fill the width of the window.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import QtQuick 6.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic 6.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Portmod"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    header: TabBar {
        id: mainTabBar
        width: parent.width

        TabButton {
            text: "Manage"
            width: implicitWidth
        }

        TabButton {
            text: "Search"
            width: implicitWidth
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: mainStackLayout
        currentIndex: mainTabBar.currentIndex

        ColumnLayout {
            id: manageTab

            RowLayout {

                TextField {
                    placeholderText: "Filter packages..."
                }

                Button {
                    text: "Filter"
                }
            }

            HorizontalHeaderView {
                id: installedPackagesHeader
                syncView: installedPackagesTable
            }

            TableView {
                id: installedPackagesTable
                columnSpacing: 1
                rowSpacing: 1
                clip: true

                model: installedPackagesModel

                Keys.onUpPressed: installedPackagesTableVerticalScrollBar.decrease()
                Keys.onDownPressed: installedPackagesTableVerticalScrollBar.increase()
                Keys.onLeftPressed: installedPackagesTableHorizontalScrollBar.decrease()
                Keys.onRightPressed: installedPackagesTableHorizontalScrollBar.increase()

                ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                    id: installedPackagesTableVerticalScrollBar
                    parent: installedPackagesTable
                }

                ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
                    id: installedPackagesTableHorizontalScrollBar
                    parent: installedPackagesTable
                }

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 300
                    implicitHeight: 25

                    Text {
                        text: display
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: searchTab
            width: parent.parent.width
            height: parent.parent.height
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my custom `QSortFilterProxyModel` and `QAbstractItemModel`:

```py
class InstalledPackagesProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, data: list[list]) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.realModel = InstalledPackagesModel(data)
        self.setSourceModel(self.realModel)

    def get_atom(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Atom:
        """
        Returns a reference to the source index instead of proxy index, to handle the sorted view.
        """
        mapped_index = self.mapToSource(index)
        data = [tuple(pkg_data_list) for pkg_data_list in self.realModel._data]
        return Atom(f"{data[mapped_index.row()][2]}/{data[mapped_index.row()][0]}")


class InstalledPackagesModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data: list[list]):
        super(InstalledPackagesModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.header_labels = ["Name", "Use Flags", "Category", "Version"]

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:  # type: ignore
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

            if isinstance(value, Atom):
                return str(value)

            return value

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        try:
            return len(self._data[0])
        # If there are no installed mods in the prefix
        except IndexError:
            return 1

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):  # type: ignore
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:  # type: ignore
            return self.header_labels[section]
        return QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: Progress]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to set the `columnWidthProvider` to this:

```
return Window.width / installedPackagesTableView.model.columnCount()
```

This is my full code for the TableView:

```
TableView {
    id: installedPackagesTableView

    property int selectedRow: 0

    focus: true
    columnSpacing: 1
    rowSpacing: 1
    clip: true
    model: installedPackagesModel

    columnWidthProvider: function () {
        return Window.width / installedPackagesTableView.model.columnCount()
    }

    rowHeightProvider: function (row) {
        return 30;
    }

    onWidthChanged: installedPackagesTableView.forceLayout()

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    Keys.onUpPressed: function () {
        if (selectedRow != 0) {
            selectedRow -= 1;
        }

        // Move scrollbar up if the selectedRow is going to be invisible
        if (selectedRow == topRow) {
            installedPackagesTableVerticalScrollBar.decrease()
        }
    }

    Keys.onDownPressed: function () {
        if (selectedRow != installedPackagesModel.rowCount() - 1) {
            selectedRow += 1;

            // Move scrollbar down if the selectedRow is going to be invisible
            if (selectedRow == bottomRow) {
                installedPackagesTableVerticalScrollBar.increase()
            }
        }
    }

    Keys.onReturnPressed: installedPackagesModel.getAtom(selectedRow)

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        id: installedPackagesTableVerticalScrollBar
    }

    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
        id: installedPackagesTableHorizontalScrollBar
    }

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        highlighted: row == installedPackagesTableView.selectedRow
        onClicked: installedPackagesTableView.selectedRow = row
        onDoubleClicked: installedPackagesModel.getAtom(row)
        text: model.display
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `anchors.fill: parent` on the `StackView` so it fills out its parent and has a proper size. Furthermore the `HorizontalHeaderView` needs to get a `implicitHeight` and the `TableView`  should set `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight` to `true`.

You need to use `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight` to span to the full width and height of layouts.

```
import QtQuick 6.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic 6.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.0
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Portmod"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    header: TabBar {
        id: mainTabBar
        width: parent.width

        TabButton { text: "Manage" }
        TabButton { text: "Search" }
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: mainStackLayout
        currentIndex: mainTabBar.currentIndex
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout {
            id: manageTab
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            RowLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true

                TextField {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    placeholderText: "Filter packages..."
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: "Filter"
                }
            }

            HorizontalHeaderView {
                id: installedPackagesHeader
                syncView: tableView
                implicitHeight: 30
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            TableView {
                id: tableView
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                columnSpacing: 1
                rowSpacing: 1
                clip: true

                columnWidthProvider: function (column) {
                    return tableView.model ? tableView.width / tableView.model.columnCount : 0
                }
                rowHeightProvider: function (row) { return 30 }

                onWidthChanged: tableView.forceLayout()

                model: TableModel {
                    TableModelColumn { display: "name" }
                    TableModelColumn { display: "color" }

                    rows: [
                        { "name": "cat", "color": "black" },
                        { "name": "dog", "color": "brown" },
                        { "name": "bird", "color": "white" }
                    ]
                }

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    Text {
                        text: display
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: searchTab
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your help. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do what I want entirely. Although, it's visible now, so thank you for that!  It doesn't stretch to fill up the rest of the window though. I was wanting the header and the table to take up the full width, and for the table to take up the rest of the height below the header and button + text field.

It ends up looking like this: https://i.imgur.com/6RaDZNO.png

Comment: @PopeRigby I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Interesting. It works just how I want it to with the QML model you provided, but it doesn't work with the custom model I derived from QAbstractItemModel. It even says this when I switch out the model and run it: "file:///home/user/Projects/portmod/portmod/_gui/main.qml:49:13: QML QQuickTableView: the delegate's implicitWidth needs to be greater than zero". I've update the original post to include my custom model.

Comment: What does tableView.model in columnWidthProvider return if output via console.log?

Comment: It outputs this a bunch of times: "qml: InstalledPackagesProxyModel(0x5632d81a8250)"

Comment: I forgot to mention, the `installedPackagesModel` in the QML is set to my custom QSortFilterProxyModel.